# How does conversion discovery work in canonical logback?

Tags: java, logback

I'm looking at https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#customConversionSpecifier.

In step 2 it says

> we must let logback know about the new `Converter`. For this purpose, we need to declare the new conversion word in the configuration file, as shown below

The `Legacy` example config is as follows:

```
<configuration>

  <conversionRule conversionWord="nanos"
                  converterClass="chapters.;layouts.MySampleConverter" />

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.;core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-6nanos [%thread] -%kvp -%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

In that configuration, it's very easy to see how the "new conversion word" is declared: with the `conversionRule` element. In the `Canonical (1.3)` example, however, no such element exists:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>

<configuration>
  <import class="ch.qos.logback.;core.ConsoleAppender"/>
  <import class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder"/>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <pattern>%-6nanos [%thread] -%kvp -%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

There's no declaration of any `nanos` conversion word, and no reference to the custom converter at all. I've also noticed that for any config including `conversionRule`, if I put it through the [canonicalizer](https://logback.qos.ch/translator/services/xml2Canon.html) (which transforms logback.xml files into canonical form) any reference to `conversionRule` and the `conversionWord` and `converterClass` is dropped entirely.

I can't find anything that explains how to specify or provide conversion rules in the canonical format. Is this a problem with the documentation/canonicalizer, or is there some behind-the-scenes magic that goes on that allows these to be equivalent despite the lack of any reference to `MySampleConverter` in the canonical configuration?